# How to programatically add constraints to a button in Swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift2, constraints

All the questions I have seen on this are for swift 1. Im trying to create a button and add constraints to it. I would like the button to be positioned at 30 x and 390 y. I would also like the size of the button to be 75 x and 75 y. Everything I have tried has not worked. Please help. Heres the code I have for creating the button(you will see that I added an image to the button so I can see it better):

```
let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "BlueBall.png")!, forState:  U IControlState.Normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Thank you. Anton

Comment: As far as I know, NSLayoutConstraint is still a part of the API in swift 2. You need to create some of those and add them to `self.view` using the method `addConstraint`(`s`).

Comment: BTW, if you use `frame`, as Rob contemplates below, you might also want to set `autoresizingMask`, too. Personally, I'd stick with constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're allowed to just set the frame how you like and leave `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to `true`. That would be the simplest answer in your case.

```
    let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
    // button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is true by default
    button.frame = CGRectMake(30, 390, 75, 75)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "BlueBall.png")!, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)
```

If you really want to do it with constraints, it's a lot more work. If your deployment target is iOS 9.0 or later, you can do this:

```
    let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "BlueBall.png")!, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)

    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
        button.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor, constant: 30),
        button.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor, constant: 390),
        button.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(75),
        button.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(75)
    ])
```